# Selective y variable in shiny plotly output

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly, selectinput

I'm trying to include a plotly plot in a shiny app where the y variable is selected by the user. I initially used ggplot2 and plotly together, and the code I have works just fine for that. But because the number of data points is quite large, the plot takes several minutes to load, so I tried switching to plotly only because I read somewhere that that makes it faster. Unfortunately I cannot get the y variable selection to work.

I have tried the suggestions given here: [Change plotly chart y variable based on selectInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980999/change-plotly-chart-y-variable-based-on-selectinput) and here: [Error: invalid first argument with R Shiny plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737409/error-invalid-first-argument-with-r-shiny-plot) and none of them work. At this point I have tried so many things I don't remember in detail, but basically I either get the error "invalid first argument" when using some variation of `yvar <- get(input$yvariable1)` and then including ~yvar in the plot function, or I get "Error: cannot set attribute on a symbol" when it's `y = ~input$yvariable1`. When I use `y = newdata[ ,input$yvariable1]` something gets plotted but it's completely wrong (the scale of the axis is up to 50k or something instead of 10 and the distribution is not right either - basically it looks nothing like when I plot it by simply entering the same y variable non-reactively).

My code looks as follows - in UI:

```
uiOutput("ySelection1")
```

in server:

```
function(input, output) {
  
  output$ySelection1 <- renderUI({
    varSelectInput("yvariable1", "Y Variable:", df[, c('PO_count_citing', 'cpc_3digits_count_citing', 'cpc_4digits_count_citing')], selected='PO_count_citing')
  })

  yvar1 <- eventReactive(input$yvariable1, {input$yvariable1})

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    newdata <- subset(df, Technology == input$type & appln_auth%in%input$PO)
    validate(no_data(nrow(newdata)))
    #yvar <- get(yvar1()) (failed attempt at making this work)
    #yvar <- get(input$yvariable1) (another failed attempt)
    scatterPlot <- plot_ly(newdata, x = ~appln_filing_year, y = ~input$yvariable1, type="scatter", mode="markers",
    # Hover text:
    text = ~paste(some text),
    color = ~appln_auth)
  })

}
```

But I can't get it to work. In the original ggplot2 version it was entered as `aes(x = appln_filing_year, y = !!yvar1(), bla bla)`

But the !! or even one ! or removing the brackets after yvar1 all throw up errors in plotly.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try `y = ~.data[[as.name(input$yvariable1)]]`

Comment: Hi YBS, thank you! I tried that but I get the error object '.newdata' not found. When I remove the . it works though!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example using `get`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

DF <- setNames(data.frame(rep(1:20, 5), mapply(runif, min = 1:5, max = 2:6, MoreArgs = list(n = 20))), c("x", paste0("y", 1:5)))
       
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("myPlot"),
  selectInput("yvariable", "Select the Y variable", paste0("y", 1:5))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    req(input$yvariable)
    plot_ly(data = DF, x = ~x, y = ~get(input$yvariable), type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried applying this but I receive the error "invalid first argument".

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example?